# Add Text Input to Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to accomplish a feature where a user can type a piece of text into an input box, click submit and they'll be taken to a webpage which includes the text they submitted in the url.

For example, if the user entered the word 'apple' in the text and clicked submit, they would be taken to [http://example.com/link.aspx?username=**apple**&jump=1](http://example.com/link.aspx?filter=0%25username=**apple**&jump=1) or if they entered the word 'orange', they would be taken to [http://example.com/link.aspx?username=**orange**&jump=1](http://example.com/link.aspx?filter=0%25username=**orange**&jump=1).

I've tried the following code, but to no avail - it doesn't send the user anywhere on submit.

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" value="11" id="input"> 
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I've edited the post and included the code I've tried but to no avail.

Comment: A regular form (without the jQuery), a submit button, and a text field named `username` would do just this with the GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you're trying to use JQuery when you can do it much easier with PHP

Form

```
<form action="form.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="n" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP side - form.php

```
header("Location: http://yourdomain/page/".$_GET['n']);
```

Comment: Because then you need both a backend and a frontend, plus more webpages.

Comment: Well its true, but on another hand with js he need to input script - which is not good solution at all. IMO faster, easier and more safe is to use php.

Comment: Besides, it's not like we're using `eval` on the input.

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me.

are you sure you added jquery before your script?

add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use jQuery for this. A simple form with get method will work fine.

```
<form name="sample" method="get">
      <input name="username" type="text" value=""/>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

This will automatically submit the form once user fills field and click submit button in the format you are looking for.